# How can DAPL offer more functionality than OFA does if DAPL relies solely on OFA as the only layer beneath it?

Tags: mpi, infiniband, intel-mpi, ofed

In my understanding if a system that only has underlying Infiniband connectivity (i.e. not iWarp or anything else which DAPL could use as an alternative) then DAPL exists solely as an abstracted layer on top of OFA/Infiniband.

If this is the case, then how can DAPL offer more functionality than OFA does if DAPL relies solely on OFA as the only layer beneath it?
[OFED stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7mQh.gif)

Comment: Check out this thread from Intel, these folks know their stuff and  explain parts of the issue better than I can https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-clusters-and-hpc-technology/topic/279244

Comment: Yes I check this thread, but the last comment is the question that nobody answered.

Comment: yeah, that is why I didn't make it an answer, it explains some different aspects but does not directly answer the question.  My guess would be that DAPL offers the most highly optimized use of OFA with the broadest range of features.  it is unlikely that someone will come up with a better performing OFA only version of those features than the ones available through DAPL which may explain the functionality difference you mention.  But that would just be a guess